# Create an array from two array PHP

Tags: php, loops

i have two arrays

```
$value_array = array('50','40','30','20','10');
$customer = array('300','200','100');
```

i want to distribute the value array to customers based on the value of customers that is taken as limit.adding values by checking it wont cross the limit that is 300 , 200 and 100.

but customer array not working one direction it should work first forward and then backward like that

i want to produce an array in form of

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 50
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 40
            [1] => 10
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 30
            [1] => 20
        )

)
```

After completing customer loop first time it should start from last to first. both array count will change , i mean count.

value array should  check 50 -> 300 , 40->200, 30->100 then from last ie, 20 ->100, 10->200 etc.

I tried like

```
$i = 0;
while($i < count($customer)){


    foreach($value_array as $k=>$value){

        $v = 0;
        if($value <= $customer[$i]){
            $customer2[$i][] = $value;
            unset($value_array[$k]);
            $v = 1;
        }
        if($v ==1){
            break;
        }

    }

    //echo $i."<br/>";
    if($i == (count($customer)-1) && (!empty($value_array))){

        $i = 0;
        $customer = array_reverse($customer, true);


    }

$i++;   
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($customer2);
```

Comment: I don't understand the reason for breaking up of the value_array in the first place. Please explain clearly what you're intending to achieve here.

Comment: What do you mean by array should check?

Comment: i edited my question please check

Comment: Nope; still don't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: see the answer that i am looking for..but its too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

```
$valueArray = array('50','40','30','20','10','0','-11');
$customer = array('300','200','100');

function parse(array $valueArr, array $customerArr)
{
    $customerCount = count($customerArr);
    $chunkedValueArr = array_chunk($valueArr, $customerCount);
    $temp = array_fill(0, $customerCount, array());

    $i = 0;
    foreach ($chunkedValueArr as $item) {
        foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
            $temp[$key][] = $value;
        }
        $temp = rotateArray($temp);
        $i++;
    }
    // if $i is odd
    if ($i & 1) {
        $temp = rotateArray($temp);
    }

    return $temp;
}

function rotateArray(array $arr)
{
    $rotatedArr = array();

    //set the pointer to the last element and add it to the second array
    array_push($rotatedArr, end($arr));

    //while we have items, get the previous item and add it to the second array
    for($i=0; $i<sizeof($arr)-1; $i++){
        array_push($rotatedArr, prev($arr));
    }

    return $rotatedArr;
}
```

`print_r(parse($valueArray, $customer));`
returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 50
            [1] => 0
            [2] => -11
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 40
            [1] => 10
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 30
            [1] => 20
        )

)
```

Comment: can u check with these arrays $valueArray = array('50','40','30','20','10','10','10','10','10','5');
$customer = array('100','80','60');   the value 5 is listing in 3rd array but it should come under 2nd array. becuase we have to check the customer array limit is crossing or not  i added **$pre_existing = isset($temp[$key]) ? array_sum($temp[$key]) : 0;
   
   
   $pre_existing+$value.'-'.$customerArr[$key]."<br/>";
   
   if($pre_existing+$value <= $customerArr[$key]){
    $temp[$key][] = $value;
   }**   But not working

Comment: can you give example, how result array should look with given values?

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 50
            [1] => 10
            [2] => 10
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 40
            [1] => 10
            [2] => 10
   [3] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 30
            [1] => 20
            [2] => 10
        )

)